# i am trying add jitsi meet in my project but i'm facing some errors in app\build.gradle

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'E:\flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 28
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_e6325ly5sewzgcnn6tjf3co8o.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_e6325ly5sewzgcnn6tjf3co8o$_run_closure2) values: [build_e6325ly5sewzgcnn6tjf3co8o$_run_closure2@877377c]

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you solve it ?